# TNS-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor 4/2016

Tags: oracle, tnsnames

I am getting this error when trying to connect to freshly installed Oracle Enterprise from either SQL Developer or Net Manager. I did try every solution that I could find with no luck.

I am trying to connect with a system account and I am able to log in with sqlplus, so I know that my credentials are correct.

listener.ora

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\Oracle\OracleUser\product\12.1.0\dbhome_2\bin\oraclr12.dll")
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\Oracle\OracleUser\product\12.1.0\dbhome_2)
    )
  )
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = C:\Oracle\OracleUser\product\12.1.0\dbhome_2\log
```

tnsnames.ora

```
LISTENER_ORCL = 
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )
```

error inside the ...\product\12.1.0\dbhome_2\log\diag\tnslsnr\iper410a\listener\trace\listener.log

```
24-APR-2016 19:10:33 * (CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=null)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER=null))(SERVICE_NAME=orcl)) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1195)) * establish * orcl * 12514
TNS-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
24-APR-2016 19:10:40 * (CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=SQL Developer)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER=my_windows_login))(SERVICE_NAME=orcl)) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1198)) * establish * orcl * 12514
TNS-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
```

It confuses me that instead of 'system' Oracle account, the error is listing my windows login account (my_windows_login).

Please advise!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have two oracle homes.

Check the output of cmd -> `tnsping orcl` command. You can see which oracle directory is being used.

Then you can check Environment Variables -> System Variable -> Path and reorder Oracle Home directories. This worked in my case.